# Can you check to see if there will be any results

Tags: mysql, mysql5

I'm displaying Spotlight post on search page.

When a user enters a keyword to search for a post I like to bring a Spotlight post using that keyword. If there is no post with that keyword then I would want to just bring any Spotlight post from database.

My questions is, can I check this in a MySQL query to see if they will be any results with this keyword, if not then ignore this keyword?

My query

```
SELECT id, title, desc 
  FROM post 
 WHERE isActive = 1 
   AND title = 'keyword'
```

but if I'm getting 0 results with this query I would like to ignore this and run this instead

```
SELECT id, title, desc 
  FROM post 
 WHERE isActive = 1
```

Comment: Passing `$keywords` straight into the SQL - I hope you're escaped it using the proper MySQL API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I have done to solve my problem.

```
$select = " SELECT id, title, desc ";
$from = ' FROM post';
$where = 'WHERE isActive=1 and title="%$keywords%"';
$sql = $select.$from.$where;
```

if no result then overwrite

```
$where = 'WHERE isActive=1';
$sql = $select.$from.$where;
```

If anyone know anyother way please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

`desc` is MySQL's [reserved keyword](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) (used for ordering results in a **desc**ending order). To use it as a column name, you need to put it in backticks

```
$select = " SELECT id, title, `desc` ";
$from = ' FROM post';
$where = 'WHERE isActive=1 and title="%$keywords%"';
$sql = $select.$from.$where;
```

Comment: this is just a example. i didn't called the column desc

Comment: Ah... please make  sure your example code is syntactically correct, because otherwise people trying to answer you will get confused... like me :)

Comment: Also I believe you want `$where = "WHERE isActive=1 and title LIKE '%$keywords%'";` not `$where = 'WHERE isActive=1 and title="%$keywords%"';` but is that an example or actual code?

Comment: What I have done is check for result if none found then try another query without any keywords. it works greate thank you for your help.